# Objective-C NSTimer update label doesn't update

Tags: objective-c, nstimer

I have two methods below. One method (`timerHit`) which gets the track duration of the current playing song, minuses 1 from it and prints it out in the log it then also updates a label with the value too. The other method (`countDown`) which repeats every second calls the `timerHit` method, however it doesn't seem to work correctly the `NSLog` statement works and repeats thus printing the value every second but the update label statement `[duration setDoubleValue:trackDuration];` doesn't work. Can anyone help me?

```
- (void)countDown {
    [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:1.0f target:self selector:@selector(timerHit:) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
}

- (void)timerHit:(NSTimer *)p_timer
{
    iTunesApplication *iTunes = [SBApplication applicationWithBundleIdentifier:@"com.apple.iTunes"];
    double trackDuration = [[iTunes currentTrack] duration];
    if( trackDuration <= 1 && [p_timer isValid] )
        [p_timer invalidate];
    trackDuration--;
    NSLog(@"%d", trackDuration);
    [duration setDoubleValue:trackDuration];
}
```

Thanks, Sami.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that duration is an instance of NSTextField (After Googling, this seems to be the case - I can't find NSLabel to be an existing object), try this;

```
[duration setStringValue:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", trackDuration]];
```

Comment: Haha, almost same reply but I like the dot notation better. :-)
Sidenote: is the timer executed on the main thread? I would expect the requirement to execute on main thread but that does not seem to be necessary for NSTimer. But if it runs on the main thread, how can iOS make sure it will always be called "in time"? Or maybe it just can't guarantee that on a 2nd thought.

Comment: Now it doesn't even show anything, and also i get the error NSTextField may not respond to -setText. Also sorry i forgot to mention this is a Mac OS X app not and iPhone app so the label is an instance of NSTextView and not UILabel.

Comment: `i forgot to mention this is a Mac OS X app not and iPhone app so the label is an instance of NSTextView and not UILabel.` Ah, that explains a lot.

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the label's text:

```
duration.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", trackDuration]];
```

Comment: Mac, not iOS--so `-[NSTextField setStringValue:]`, not `-[UILabel setText:]`.